# Can windows 10 standalone executables (in Python) run on Windows 11?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, exe

I actually made an executable with some ui in tkinter for automating some tasks in my Windows 10 computer. But since Windows 11 started rolling out, I was wondering if my app can still run in Windows 11.

Comment: Not sure but in any case of error you can use Windows `Compatibility` option.

Comment: That would entirely depend on what your program does, it's impossible to say without that knowledge. That said, unless you're digging deep into undocumented things or deprecated APIs there should be no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will indeed work, if your app doesn't use features that were deprecated in Windows 11. You can also run it in compatibility mode if there is some unexpected behavior.